# How to convert a systemctl command to supervisord command

Tags: docker, dockerfile, supervisord

I have found the following Dockerfile

```
FROM centos

# following http://www.pacb.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/09/SMRT-Analysis-Software-Installation-v2.3.0.pdf

MAINTAINER harekrishna@gmail.com

ENV SMRT_ROOT=/opt/smrtanalysis/
ENV SMRT_USER=smrtanalysis
ENV SMRT_GROUP=smrtanalysis

RUN yum groupinstall -y "Development Tools"
RUN yum install -y redhat-lsb net-tools

RUN groupadd $SMRT_GROUP
RUN adduser \
  --gid $SMRT_GROUP \
  --home-dir $SMRT_ROOT \
  --create-home \
  --shell /bin/bash \
  $SMRT_USER

USER $SMRT_USER
WORKDIR $SMRT_ROOT

RUN curl -LO -# \
  http://files.pacb.com/software/smrtanalysis/2.3.0/smrtanalysis_2.3.0.140936.run

RUN curl -LO -# \
  https://s3.amazonaws.com/files.pacb.com/software/smrtanalysis/2.3.0/smrtanalysis-patch_2.3.0.140936.p5.run

RUN bash \
  smrtanalysis_2.3.0.140936.run \
  -p smrtanalysis-patch_2.3.0.140936.p5.run \
  --rootdir $SMRT_ROOT \
  --batch \
  --ignore-syscheck \
  --jmstype NONE

ADD ./run /usr/local/bin
#RUN chmod 755 ./run

EXPOSE 8080

CMD ["/usr/local/bin/run"]
```

Startup scripts:

```
$SMRT_ROOT/admin/bin/smrtportald-initd start 
$SMRT_ROOT/admin/bin/kodosd start
```

How is it possible to covnert the two above commands to supervised commands?

Thank you in advance.

Mic

Comment: With absolutely no context, there's no way anyone could help out... The commented link inside the Dockerfile is dead, and we have no way of knowing what any of those commands do without installing it ourselves. Either way, I think this question is better suited for other Stack* forums, since it's not actually related to Dockerfiles themselves (keep in mind that although you're using a container, it's still basically a shell running predetermined commands in an isolated context - if you need it to run something, you must have a **blocking** entrypoint script that runs what you need).

Comment: Also, the title seems considerably misleading... systemd and supervisord are two "service managers", they have nothing to do with Docker at all. Furthermore, systemctl is just the CLI for systemd, as supervisorctl is for supervisord. I also think there was a confusion between init.d and systemd services, since if they actually were systemd services, the start command would be in a `systemctl start ...` call (or at least `service ... start`, if confused with SysV), opposite to just calling the services with a `start` command argument.